# Passing component as prop to child component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to pass multiple badge components as props to a component.

```
<MouseOverPopover
  data={
    row.original.region == null ? (
      "-"
    ) : !Array.isArray(row.original.region) ? (
      <Badge variant="info"> {row.original.region} </Badge>
    ) : (
      row.original.region.map((region) => (
        <Badge variant="info" style={{ margin: "2px" }} key={region}>
          {region}
        </Badge>
      ))
    )
  }
/>
```

Here is the MouseOverPopover component

```
export default function MouseOverPopover({ data }) {
```

I then use `{ data }` to display the content.

However, the badges are not rendering and I got this error in the log

`Failed prop type: Invalid prop variant of value info supplied to ForwardRef(Badge)`

I am guessing that passing component inside props is probably the wrong way to do that. Is there a right way I can do this?

Comment: It is better to pass the "component" but not as JSX, i.e. `Badge` versus `<Badge variant.... />`, if that makes sense. Is the component passed ever only `Badge`? Seems you could internalize this logic in `MouseOverPopover` and simply pass `row.original.region` as the "data".

Comment: I would like the component `MouseOverPopover` to be used as a generic component that does not only show badges.

Answer (score 0):

#### First point: error it self says

`Failed prop type: Invalid prop variant of value info supplied to ForwardRef(Badge)`

Means below [Badge](https://material-ui.com/components/badges/#badge) with props ***variant***="***info***" is invalid.

```
<Badge variant="info"> {row.original.region} </Badge>
       ^^^
```

There are only two variant for Badge `'dot'| 'standard'` check [here](https://material-ui.com/api/badge/#props)

#### Second point: different way to pass your props

Here [React official site](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) Composition vs Inheritance

[Containment](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment) is one of the way to pass your props `Badges/any other components` to `MouseOverPopover (as it represent generic “boxes”)` component;

As per my opinion do this

```
const getBadges = () => {
    if (row.original.region == null) {
      return "-";
    } else if (!Array.isArray(row.original.region)) {
      return <Badge variant="standard">{row.original.region}</Badge>;
    } else {
      return row.original.region.map((region) => (
        <Badge variant="standard" style={{ margin: "2px" }} key={region}>
          {region}
        </Badge>
      ));
    }
  };
  <MouseOverPopover>{getBadges()}</MouseOverPopover>;
```

MouseOverPopover component:

```
export default MouseOverPopover = ({ children }) => {
   return (
     ...
     {children} //badge will render here
     ...
   )
}
```

Your code will also works you used `your own convention (data={...})` and I used `children` as props